# Java while loop can not detect change by thread

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I'm new in java thread, I write a test program:

//MyTest.java

```
public class MyTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        int n;

        thread.start();

        while (true){
            //System.out.print("");

            n = MyThread.num;
            if (n != 0){
                System.out.println("<Num> has been modified to " + n);
                if (n == -1) break;

                MyThread.num = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Main thread terminated!");
    }
}
```

//MyThread.java

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public static int num = 0;

    public void run(){
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int n;

        while (true){
            System.out.print("Type a number: ");
            n = input.nextInt();
            if (n == -1) break;
            num = n;
        }

        input.close();
        System.out.println("MyThread thread terminated!");
    }
}
```

When I run this, It show a message: *"Type a number: "* and I input some number. But then, the **while loop** on main class can not detect the **`MyThread.num`** has been modified.
So it prompt a message, and so on... Even I type -1, the second thread terminated, but the main thread doesn't show any message and never terminated.

I try to fix by add a code `System.out.print("")` below the **`while(true)`** (as I marked a comment above). Then It work but when type -1, it still can not detect.

I'm don't know why the command System.out.print("") can make it work(but not a good solution) and what is problem with my code. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `static int num` is not marked `volatile`. Java "knows" that `num` is not going to change after the first read, so it is not reading it again.

Change the declaration to

```
static volatile int num;
```

to fix this problem. This will force memory reads on each access to `num`.

Note: static variables are *not* a good way of communicating between threads.

Answer (score 1):

As for the problew with detecting -1, your break statement prevents it. You should break out of the loop **after** updating num.